# Total class template specialization with container template

Tags: c++, class, templates, containers

I am trying to create a disjoint set class that works for the different container types in the stl (vector, dequeue and array) with a template but I am having trouble doing a specialization for the array container since it has a different initialization than vector and dequeue. Array takes two arguments while the other two take one. This is what I have tried to do:

```
template <int N,template<typename ,typename...>class Container>

class disjoint_set{

private:

    Container<int> vertices;
    Container<int> root;
.
.
.

template <int N> //Class specialization for array
class disjoint_set<N,std::array<int,N>>{

private:

    Container<int> vertices;
    Container<int> root;
.
.
.
```

I am getting the following error:
template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template

Comment: I posted an answer. If it helped, please consider vote/acceptance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `N` parameter to the first (more general) template?

Comment: @JaMiT use it for the disjoint_set constructor since for std::array you have to pass values for the parameters of every object. That way I can just use N inside the constructor. If there is another way I would love to know though!

Comment: @AGH97 If the constructor is relevant, then it should be part of the question. Also, I thought you were using `std::array` only in the specialization, not in the more general template.

Comment: @JaMiT it's not that i'm only using in the specialization I don't think you can implement it in the same template as a std::vector or std::deque since it takes an extra argument in its constructor <type, size> so I opted for a specialization for it. The code ended up looking like this https://pastebin.com/kwumFprp, if there's a better way to do it lmk!

Comment: @AGH97 The type and size of a `std::array` are not parameters to the array's constructor. They are template parameters, hence part of the type.

Comment: @AGH97 There probably is a better way to do what you want to do, but it's become too much work to figure out what you want to do. So I'll leave this to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because template template parameter `Container` is declared to have a type as a second parameter while you are passing an `int`. This can be easily fixed though:

```
template <int N, typename Container>
class disjoint_set{

template <int N> //Class specialization for array
class disjoint_set<N, std::array<int, N>>{
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one also lets me use N for the disjoint_set constructor so I can have a constructor with no parameters! (made life easier for the std::array specialization)

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is giving the error, since a type is entered as the template template parameter. Assuming that specialization for any N is not desired,  and it should also be usable  with other containers (vector and deque) which are differently formed, a correct way looks like:

```
template <class Container> // template <typename Container>

class disjoint_set{

private:

    Container vertices;
    Container root;
.
.
.
};
```

Without any specialization. Unless `disjoint_set` really acts differently for each type of the containers.
And  the container should be simply given at the time of construction of objects, like:

```
disjoint_set<std::array<int, 56> > object1(...);
disjoint_set<std::vector<int> > object2(...);
disjoint_set<std::deque<int> > object3(...);
```

Good Luck!